How do representations relate to particle statistics?
Wigner's classification essentially says that elementary particles are unitary irreducible representations of the Poincaré group. Can you get the particle's statistics (e.g. its partition function) from these representations?
The closest I can find in the literature involves the Schur polynomials. For Fermi-Dirac statistics, you want to follow the Pauli exclusion principle, so you use
$$s^d_{(1,1,\dots,1)}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)=\sum_{sym}x_1x_2\cdots x_d,$$
and the partition function for $n$ particles is
$$\mathcal{Z} = \sum_{d\le n}s^d_{(1,1,\dots,1)}.$$
As $n\to\infty$, you get the grand canonical partition function
$$\mathcal{Z} = \sum_{d=1}^{\infty}s^d_{(1,1,\dots,1)} = \prod (1+x_i).$$
Similarly, for Bose-Einstein statistics, you use
$$s^d_{(d)}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)=\sum_{i_1+i_2+\cdots+i_k=d}x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\cdots x_k^{i_k},$$
and the grand canonical partition function
$$\mathcal{Z} = \sum_{d=1}^{\infty}s^d_{(d)} = \prod (1-x_i)^{-1}.$$

My own thoughts:
The representation for the $(1,1,\dots,1)$-partition of the symmetric group is just $\rho(\sigma) = \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$. This is faithful to the smaller group
$$S_d/\ker(\rho) = C_2 = \{1, -1\}.$$
It turns out that
$$\prod_{g\in C_2} (1-x^{|g|})^{-\rho(g)} = \frac{1-x^2}{1-x} = 1+x$$
gives the Fermi-Dirac statistics. Similarly, the $(d)$-partition has the representation $\rho(\sigma) = 1$, which is faithful to the trivial group, and
$$\prod_{g\in\{1\}} (1-x^{|g|})^{-\rho(g)} = (1-x)^{-1}$$
gives the Bose-Einstein statistics. Taking a logarithm, we have the density of states
$$\Omega = -\sum \rho(g)\ln (1-x^{|g|}) = \sum\rho(g)\left[\frac{x^{|g|}}{1}+\frac{x^{2|g|}}{2}+\frac{x^{3|g|}}{3}+\cdots\right]$$
which looks like projecting the function
$$\left[\frac{x^{|g|}}{1}+\frac{x^{2|g|}}{2}+\frac{x^{3|g|}}{3}+\cdots\right]$$
onto the particle's representation. My loose interpretation is that each term is a system with $k$ particles ergodically diffusing through the group.

Note: Wigner’s classification associates one-particle states with projective unitary representations of the Poincaré group. A big difference!

Note: The question’s title is a different question than stated in the body. If you are asking the question stated in your title, then there is a nuanced relationship between representations of the fundamental group of a classical configuration space and particle statistics. Cf. Leinaas & Myrheim.

The Wigner classification ultimately tells you that you can classify particle states by mass and spin. Mass can be $0$ or a positive real number. Spin can take on any non-negative half integer value.
To connect the Wigner classification to particle statistics, you need the spin-statistics theorem, which states that particles with integer spin obey bosonic statistics and particles with half-integer spin obey fermionic statistics. The Wigner classification does not itself imply the spin-statistics theorem. The proofs of the spin-statistics require extra information, for example causality, which implies that fields either commute or anti-commute on a space-like hypersurface.
